# Launch the Android x86 image on the target using ethernet

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, x86, ethernet

I want to launch android image to my x86 based target device by using Ethernet in eclipse. Presently i can boot android using USB or CD-ROM. So is it possible this directly over ethernet?? so i can debug my kernel and driver using ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out first.

[Make the default android emulator faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155296/is-there-an-android-simulator-not-the-default-emulator-similar-to-the-iphone-o/5219368#5219368)

Configuring to Listen Via  Ethernet/ WiFi:

To use your device via WiFi/Ethernet, the device's adbd (Android Device Bridge in the device) needs to be configured to listen via Ethernet first. The adbd by default listens to USB port.

Here is a simple Tutorial for doing this did by me,

http://sree.cc/google/connecting-devices-to-adb-via-wifii-or-lan

For Debugging,
You need to setup the following...

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-projects-cmdline.html#debuggingPort