# Why does installing an app on the Android emulator via ADB take so long?

Tags: android, android-emulator, ionic-framework, adb

I'm developing an app with Ionic. I've built and signed my app to run it on an emulator. Installing the app via `adb` takes an *incredibly* long time. The signed app is 28.6MB, yet it takes **7 minutes** to install.

My AVD is running 'Android 5.1.1 - API Level 22' on the 'Intel Atom (x86_64)' CPU/ABI. The device has 2GB of RAM with a 32MB VM heap. It has 1GiB of internal storage and 1GiB of SD card storage. The screen resolution of the device is 450x800 (the device is a clone of the Nexus 4, with just the screen size altered so it doesn't have to be scaled to fit on my screen). 'Use Host GPU' is enabled, and I do also have HAXM and it states it is working fine.

I've tried to run the emulator with the `-netdelay 0`, `-netfast`, and various other flags in various combinations that I've lost track of.

I've tried just setting up a dumb web server to download the APK on the device and install it that way, and that works, but I want to automate this task.

To be clear, the emulator itself is perfectly fine, it's nice and smooth, it's just running `adb install whatever.apk` that's incredibly slow.

Is there a way to improve the transfer speed via `adb install`?

Comment: the emulator has always been slow, nothing you can really do about it except get a device

Comment: ... or use Genymotion.

Comment: Well damn, that seems really lame. I'll give Genymotion a try, thanks @krislarson

Comment: Seven minutes is an absurd amount of time. Is that time taken entirely by `adb push`?

Comment: @Seer I'm still mystified why Google chose QEMU over VirtualBox.

Comment: @fadden It's how long it takes to just transfer the apk to the emulator via `adb install`. Perhaps I'll give `adb push` a try.

Comment: @krislarson: VirtualBox is x86-only, QEMU does ARM. Early Android had a "simulator" build that ran on the x86 (or PPC) desktop, which allowed fast execution and the use of valgrind, but it was discontinued because of the cost of maintaining it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5159881/294248

Comment: Well, the result of `adb push` is the same: `82 KB/s (28634313 bytes in 340.439s)`

Comment: @fadden I can understand about the ARM support, but holy crap, waiting for that emulator is painful when you've got stuff to get out the door...

Comment: (Almost) Everything in the emulator is Virtual Memory (disk).  If you look at your disk when emulator is running you will see it gets thrashed.  Now, add Win10 on top of that.  It's a killer.  Win10 is disk-crazy on it's own.  Anyways, I upgraded my HDD to an SSD and the emulator absolutely flies.  First time I tried starting up an emulator image it started so fast I was shocked.  @Seer as you noted, the copy of the APK is really slow so the SSD obviously helps there too.  It's really quite nice with the SSD.  But with an HDD.  Terrible and unusable at times.